# How can I make my yelp button open the yelp page in a new tab?

Tags: html

the html code for my yelp button is:

```
<div id="yelp-biz-badge-plain-5VrT1XzJPlN0XM5NfZS21g"><a href="http://www.yelp.com/biz/curvesetter-tutoring-los-angeles-2">Check out CurveSetter Tutoring on Yelp</a></div><script type="text/javascript">(function(d, t) {var g = d.createElement(t);var s = d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];g.id = "yelp-biz-badge-script-plain-5VrT1XzJPlN0XM5NfZS21g";g.src = "//dyn.yelpcdn.com/biz_badge_js/en_US/plain/5VrT1XzJPlN0XM5NfZS21g.js";s.parentNode.insertBefore(g, s);}(document, 'script'));</script>
```

I tried adding

```
target="_blank"
```

before href and a but it still doesn't open up in a new tab. any thoughts?
thanks!

Comment: I couldn't flag this as a duplicate, since the original does not have an accepted answer, but see my response to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42150248/788445

Answer (score 0):

target="_blank" will work. The below code works for me.

```
<div id="yelp-biz-badge-plain-5VrT1XzJPlN0XM5NfZS21g"><a href="http://www.yelp.com/biz/curvesetter-tutoring-los-angeles-2" target="_blank">Check out CurveSetter Tutoring on Yelp</a></div>
```

[working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ubR5m/225/)

Answer (score 0):

`target="_blank"` works just fine if used *after* the href.

```
<a href="http://www.yelp.com/biz/curvesetter-tutoring-los-angeles-2" target="_blank">Check out CurveSetter Tutoring on Yelp</a>
```